# Handling kill on linux service - .NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, linux, service, .net-core

I want to write a Linux service (like an Windows service) but I don't know how to safely stop this service.

I read about

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += MethodInvokedOnSigTerm;
```

but it not exists on .NET Core 1.1.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you able to update your app to use `.Net Core 1.2`, it can be done via [`AppDomain.ProcessExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) event, but in `.Net Core 1.1` it's not possible, according to [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/8565).

Note that you'll need to reference at least `Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.2.0-beta` in order to use the newer APIs. Also to reference that newer versions you will need to have a newer set of `CLI` tools **at least preview 4** version of the tools. You may find a new API features availability [here](https://apisof.net/).

According that site, [`System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Unloading) event **does exists since `.NET Core 1.0`** in [`System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Loader/). Did you try to install that package? I think that it will resolve your problem.

```
using System.Runtime.Loader;

AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += MethodInvokedOnSigTerm;
```

Comment: AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading is working on .Net Core 2.0